# Selecting a random permutation with weights on elements

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose we want to choose a random permutation of `{1,2,...,n}`, but with positive probabilities `p(i)` on element `i`, and the probability that `i` is the first element in the permutation is `p(i)`, and then if `i` is chosen as the first element then the probability that the second element in the permutation is `j` is `p(j) / (1 - p(i))`, and so forth, where the probability that element `m` is chosen at a given position is always proportional to `p(m)`. What is an efficient way to generate the random permutation? Naively, we can pick the first element in `O(log n)` time after calculating the cumulative sums of the `p(i)`, but then if the chosen element is around the middle of the list then updating the cumulative sums of probabilities takes `O(n)` time, leading to an `O(n^2)` algorithm.

One thought I had was that if all the `p(i)` are proportional to `1/n` (within bounded constant factors), then we can achieve expected `O(n log n)` time by allowing duplicates for a while (just redraw if a duplicate is obtained), until the sum of probabilities of elements chosen so far exceeds 1/2. Then remove all chosen elements and update the cumulative sums of `p(i)` for the remaining unchosen elements.  But this doesn't work if the probabilities of elements are out of order and very skewed, like `1/2,1/4,1/8...`. But then I thought, what if we put the `i` in increasing order according to `p(i)` before calculating cumulative sums, and followed a similar strategy, and when the sum of `p(i)` of chosen elements exceeds some fraction of the sum of `p(i)` in the current set being chosen from, then update the cumulative sums starting with the largest `p(i)` and working backwards removing chosen elements and updating cumulative sums of `p(i)` until the sum of `p(i)` of unchosen elements is above some fraction of the cumulative sum of elements not removed. Does this or another strategy give expected `O(n log n)` time? Can someone fill in the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially looking for answer to this question: ["What is a good datastructure to keep cumulative values in?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922962/what-is-a-good-datastructure-to-keep-cumulative-values-in)

There are two answers which lead to an `O(n log n)` algorithm. [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/923360/1956010) proposes a binary tree which additionally tracks the sum of all child nodes. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922996/1956010) mentions [Cumulative Frequency Tables](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/cumulative.html) which is basically the same idea.

Comment: Thanks! This data structure, with some very minor additional details to do the sampling using just one rand() call per element in the permutation, makes it deterministic `O(n log n)` time with optimal `n` rand() calls, even better than expected `O(n log n)` time with expected `O(n)` rand() calls.